# match c++ constructors with regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match constructor functions in C++ code. For instance, given a file that has the following content:

```
Foo::foo // 1
  Foo::Foo // 2
Foo::~Foo // 3
Foo::Foo(std::string) // 4
Logger::removeAppender(PLogAppender*) // 5
Logger::error(std::string&) // 6
```

I'd like the expression to find lines 2 and 4.
The thing I came up with is this:

```
\(\w\+\)::\1
```

which matches the required lines, but also stuff I don't want:

Logge**r**::**r**emoveAppender(PLogAppender*)

Logg**er**::**er**ror(std::string&)

where I've highlighted the matching characters from the expression. I understand the issue is that the regex finds the same subset of characters before and after `::`, but I don't know how to deal with it. How can I change my expression to match only constructors?

**EDIT**

The reason for needing this... I'm working on a large C++ project which, unfortunately, uses a lot of static initialisation. We recently upgraded our compiler to g++ version 9.3.1 and started experiencing the static initialisation order fiasco. At this point, I'm trying to find out the order of initialisation in the old working code. I was therefore thinking to use gdb with rbreak to match constructors so I can see what is initialised first. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A regex wouldn’t be the right tool for the job. What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Match (but don't capture) a whitespace before the capture group?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen correct

Comment: Add lots of logging and tracing in your current code. For example just a `std::cout << "Foo::Foo(...)" << std::endl;` at the start of all constructors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I like that idea, but unfortunately the project contains thousand of cpp files and classes to do that manually. Can you suggest a way to automate that? I'm thinking it would require regex again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `\s` to make sure there are spaces ahead of the definition, also match for the arguments as well:

```
(?<=\s|^)(\w+)::\1\s*(\((?:.|\n)*?\))*
```

Try it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/70o68)